# While cross compiling the cmake package getting error as undefined symbol: GSS_C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE in yocto project

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, yocto, yocto-dunfell

```
| make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall

| make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/workspace_hdd/vijay/Yocto3.1.6_Atom_new/Git_Repo/BUILD/i686_64/poky-dunfell-23.0.6/build_libwebp/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cmake-native/3.16.5-r0/build'

| make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'preinstall'.

| make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/workspace_hdd/vijay/Yocto3.1.6_Atom_new/Git_Repo/BUILD/i686_64/poky-dunfell-23.0.6/build_libwebp/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cmake-native/3.16.5-r0/build'

| Install the project...

| bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake

| bin/cmake: symbol lookup error: /opt/workspace_hdd/vijay/Yocto3.1.6_Atom_new/Git_Repo/BUILD/i686_64/poky-dunfell-23.0.6/build_libwebp/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cmake-native/3.16.5-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4: undefined symbol: GSS_C_NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE

| make: *** [Makefile:143: install] Error 127

| WARNING: /opt/workspace_hdd/vijay/Yocto3.1.6_Atom_new/Git_Repo/BUILD/i686_64/poky-dunfell-23.0.6/build_libwebp/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/cmake-native/3.16.5-r0/temp/run.do_install.2856152:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
```

I checked whether the GSS_C_NT* is really undefined or not in libcurl.so.4. Yes it is.

Even I explicitly added the path LDLIBRARYPATH to current library path. Still, I don't have enough luck to overcome this. Expecting some help here

I'm expecting to cross compile the cmake(3.16.5) and cmake-native packages for my project.Im using dunfell 3.1.6 version